# Fit sine wave with a distorted time-base

Tags: matlab, time, curve-fitting, distortion, trigonometry

I want to know the best way to fit a sine-wave with a distorted time base, in Matlab.

The distortion in time is given by a n-th order polynomial (n~10), of the form `t_distort = P(t)`.

For example, consider the distortion `t_distort = 8 + 12t + 6t^2 + t^3` (which is just the power series expansion of `(t-2)^3`).

This will distort a sine-wave as follows:

[image: IMG]

I want to be able to find the distortion given this distorted sine-wave. (i.e. I want to find the function `t = G(t_distort)`, but `t_distort = P(t)` is unknown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an analytical driven route that takes `asin` of the signal with **proper** unwrapping of the angle. Then you can fit a polynomial using `polyfit` on the angle or using other fit methods (search for `fit` and see). Last, take a sin of the fitted function and compare the signal to the fitted one...  see this pedagogical example:

```
% generate data
t=linspace(0,10,1e2);
x=0.02*(t+2).^3;
y=sin(x);

% take asin^2 to obtain points of "discontinuity" where then asin hits +-1
da=(asin(y).^2);
[val locs]=findpeaks(da); % this can be done in many other ways too...

% construct the asin according to the proper phase unwrapping
an=NaN(size(y));
an(1:locs(1)-1)=asin(y(1:locs(1)-1));
for n=2:numel(locs)
    an(locs(n-1)+1:locs(n)-1)=(n-1)*pi+(-1)^(n-1)*asin(y(locs(n-1)+1:locs(n)-1));
end
an(locs(n)+1:end)=n*pi+(-1)^(n)*asin(y(locs(n)+1:end));

r=~isnan(an);
p=polyfit(t(r),an(r),3);

figure;  
subplot(2,1,1); plot(t,y,'.',t,sin(polyval(p,t)),'r-');
subplot(2,1,2); plot(t,x,'.',t,(polyval(p,t)),'r-');
title(['mean error ' num2str(mean(abs(x-polyval(p,t))))]);
```

[image]

```
p =

    0.0200    0.1200    0.2400    0.1600
```

The reason I preallocate with `NaN`and avoid taking the `asin` at points of discontinuity (locs) is to reduce the error of the fit later. As you can see, for a 100 points between 0,10 the average error is of the order of floating point accuracy, and the polynomial coefficients are as exact as you can have them.

The fact that you are not taking a derivative (as in the very elegant Hilbert transform) allows to be numerically exact. For the same conditions the Hilbert transform solution will have a much bigger average error (order of unity vs 1e-15).

The only limitation of this method is that you need enough points in the regime where the asin flips direction and that function inside the `sin` is well behaved. If there's a sampling issue you can truncate the data and only maintain a smaller range closer to zero, such that it'll be enough to characterize the function inside the `sin`. After all, you don't need millions op points to fit to a 3 parameter function.

Comment: Great answer @natan! Ultimately I want to fit a sine to a noisy distorted sine with a slopping baseline, such as the one in the image.

![IMG](http://i58.tinypic.com/xaxr3b.png)

As this is not a perfectly normalised sine between -1 and 1, will there be any problems with the method you have suggested?

Comment: I dont think this will be a robust method to work with noisy data, as it uses analytic expressions, and so the points of unwrapping will be harder to pinpoint, and the more these points there are the more error will be carried from one point to the next. The signal will have to be smoothed and normalized before trying to use such a scheme, and finding the "peaks" will have to involve signal processing better than the current `findpeaks`... I'm not saying it's impossible, but I also don't think that this is the easy way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If your resolution is high enough, then this is basically an angle-demodulation problem. The standard way to demodulate an angle-modulated signal is to take the derivative, followed by an envelope detector, followed by an integrator.

Since I don't know the exact numbers you're using, I'll show an example with my own numbers. Suppose my original timebase has 10 million points from 0 to 100:

```
t = 0:0.00001:100;
```

I then get the distorted timebase and calculate the distorted sine wave:

```
td = 0.02*(t+2).^3;
yd = sin(td);
```

Now I can demodulate it. Take the "derivative" using approximate differences divided by the step size from before:

```
ydot = diff(yd)/0.00001;
```

The envelope can be [easily detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17798825/1188632):

```
envelope = abs(hilbert(ydot));
```

This gives an approximation for the derivative of P(t). The last step is an integrator, which I can approximate using a cumulative sum (we have to scale it again by the step size):

```
tdguess = cumsum(envelope)*0.00001;
```

This gives a curve that's almost identical to the original distorted timebase (so, it gives a good approximation of P(t)):

[image]

You won't be able to get the constant term of the polynomial since we made our approximation from its derivative, which of course eliminates the constant term. You wouldn't even be able to find a unique constant term mathematically from just `yd`, since infinitely many values will yield the same distorted sine wave. You can get the other three coefficients of P(t) using polyfit if you know the degree of P(t) (ignore the last number, it's the constant term):

```
>> polyfit(t(1:10000000), tdguess, 3)

ans =

    0.0200    0.1201    0.2358    0.4915
```

This is pretty close to the original, aside from the constant term: 0.02*(t+2)^3 = 0.02t^3 + 0.12t^2 + 0.24t + 0.16.

You wanted the inverse mapping Q(t). Can you do that knowing a close approximation for P(t) as found so far?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - really enlightening! Yes, I am able to do the inverse mapping. One question I have however, is when you take the derivative of yd, you divide by the step-size of the original time vector. As I do not know what this I (I am trying to find t), shall I just use the average time-division for td? Thanks

Comment: You can actually omit the step size from both the derivative and integral commands, since they'll cancel each other out anyway.

Comment: I am actually having some problems using the inverse mapping to fit the distorted sine wave. Do you have some simple code for the end of this process?

Comment: This solution is brilliant! I've been testing it for my own application, though, and I have a few questions. First - it doesn't seem to work unless td is monotonically increasing. This isn't an issue in my case - but would there be anyway around it? (eg. try 'td = t - t^2/max(t)', tdguess flips at the inflection point). Second, it is very susceptible to a little noise. Any ideas around this? I've had some success filtering yd first. Third, error accumulates and gets worse towards the end. Seems like there should be a way around this, since there is nothing special about the order of the data.