# Fit noisy sine wave with a distorted time-base

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, noise, distortion, trigonometry

I recently asked a question about fitting a sine wave with a distorted time base, and had some great answers at the following link: [Fit sine wave with a distorted time-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899473/fit-sine-wave-with-a-distorted-time-base/23901399?noredirect=1#comment37071472_23901399)

However, I would like to perform a similar fit, but now the signal is noisy. I assume I will have to do some normalisation between -1 and 1, and also remove the slow drift.

The original question is as follows:

> I want to know the best way to fit a sine-wave with a distorted time base, in Matlab.
>
> The distortion in time is given by a n-th order polynomial (n~10), of the form `t_distort = P(t)`.
>
> For example, consider the distortion `t_distort = 8 + 12t + 6t^2 + t^3` (which is just the power series expansion of `(t-2)^3`).
>
> This will distort a sine-wave as follows:
>
> [image: IMG]
>
> I want to be able to find the distortion given this distorted sine-wave. (i.e. I want to find the function `t = G(t_distort)`, but `t_distort = P(t)` is unknown.)

Now instead of finding the distortion of a distorted sin-wave when it is perfectly normalised between -1 and 1 (and has no other distortion other than the time-base), I would like to find the distortion of a distorted sine-wave which is noisy and also has a drift. (N.B. I am not concerned with this drift at all, and preferably, it would be removed). Such a signal would be as follows:

[image: IMG]

Comment: Do you want the distortion, or the sine wave?

Comment: Ultimately, the sine wave, but I am pretty sure I can get this from the distortion.

Comment: The distortion occurs at higher frequencies than the sine wave.  Just apply a high-pass filter, and reduce the cutoff frequency until the higher frequencies disappear.